# How can I summon an Armor stand with arms?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need help on getting armor stands *with arms* in Minecraft. Whenever I try it just says "Unable to summon object". I am playing **Minecraft 1.11.2** and thus am looking for a command for that is not **1.7.10** or below.

Comment: You need to provide us with the command you're using that's giving you that error.

Comment: Wait. DO amour stands not have arms in Java?

Answer (score 3):

```
/summon minecraft:armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {ShowArms:1b}
```

I also recommend [this site](http://haselkern.com/Minecraft-ArmorStand/) which can help you build commands for Armor stands.

Answer (score 0):

The commands are as follows:

```
/data merge entity @e[type=armor_stand,sort=nearest,limit=1] {ShowArms:1}
```

which will change the nearest armor stand into an armor stand with arms.

```
/summon minecraft:armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {ShowArms:1}
```

which will summon a new armor stand with arms shown.